# Python удаление дубликатов в списке с сохранением порядка

Tags: python

необходимо из списка удалить дубликаты. 
Удаляю так: `href_list = list(set(href_list))`

Но рушится порядок, необходимо порядок сохранить. Можете что-нибудь посоветовать?

Comment: хорошо описано давным давно в [английском источнике](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Answer (score 3):

Без использования дополнительных модулей:

```
old_list = [3,5,4,2,3,4,8,7,6,9]
new_list = []
[new_list.append(item) for item in old_list if item not in new_list]
print (new_list)
```

Вывод:

> [3, 5, 4, 2, 8, 7, 6, 9]

[Подсмотрено на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15990766/5308259).

Answer (score 2):

Для Python 3.5+ / Python 2.7+:

```
In [94]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [95]: res = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([1,3,1,2,5,2,3,1]))

In [96]: res
Out[96]: [1, 3, 2, 5]
```

Начиная с Python 3.7 [`dict` гарантирует порядок ключей, который был использован при вставке](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping):

> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion
>   order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

```
In [98]: res = list(dict.fromkeys([1,3,1,2,5,2,3,1]))

In [99]: res
Out[99]: [1, 3, 2, 5]
```

---

[Сравнение скорости разных подходов для получения уникальных элементов списка с сохранением порядка и без...](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/fastest-way-to-uniquify-a-list-in-python-3.6)

PS [аналогичный вопрос в англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order)

---

Сравнение производительности для списка из 100.000 целых чисел:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from random import randint

lst = [randint(0, 10**5) for _ in range(10**6)]

def ord_dict(seq):
    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(seq))

def dict37(seq):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(seq))

def anykeyschik(seq):
    new_list = []
    return [new_list.append(item) for item in lst if item not in new_list]

def dave_kirby(seq):
    seen = set()
    return [x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
```

---

```
In [114]: %timeit anykeyschik(lst)
55.2 s ± 9.48 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [115]: %timeit dave_kirby(lst)
17.1 ms ± 1.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [116]: %timeit dict37(lst)
12.9 ms ± 417 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [117]: %timeit ord_dict(lst)
21.3 ms ± 845 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```